# What is the meaning of scope:true in angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I understand that if `scope:false`, this means that the directive will have no scope of its own.

If `scope:{something}` this means there will be an isolated scope for the directive.

What about `scope:true` ?

what does it mean? and what is it good for?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tells Angular to create a new scope for that directive. If omitted, the directive would rely on the current scope (the controller's in most cases)

From docs:

> SCOPE
>   If set to true, then a new scope will be created for this directive. If multiple directives on the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created. The new scope rule does not apply for the root of the template since the root of the template always gets a new scope.

See: [$compile](http://goo.gl/VWSpR) for further information.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking all over for this documentation. Never would have thought to look under $compile?!?